# Grouping rows from one MySQL table in another

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a recipe web-application, and want to build the recipe 'Steps' into a MySQL table, which can then be grouped together into 'Stages' - i.e. multiple steps.
Building the base table is trivial as it's all in CSV anyway from a previous piece of work, but what i'm trying to understand is how can I build a second table which will be comprised of several rows from table 1?

TABLE 1 ('Steps'):

```
Step_#      Step_Desc     Consumable     Tool      Recipe
--------------------------------------------------------
  1       Add ingredient    Sugar         Bowl        n/a
  2       Add ingredient    Butter        Bowl        n/a
  3       Mix base ings.     n/a         Mixer       FN_1
  4       Add ingredient     Eggs         Bowl        n/a
  5       Add ingredient    Flour         Bowl        n/a
  6       Mix ingredients    n/a         Mixer       FN_1
  7       Transfer to tray   n/a          Tray        n/a
  8       Place in oven      n/a         Oven      200C/50min
  9       Remove to cool     n/a         Rack       30 min
--- and so on for 400+ steps
```

TABLE 2 ('Stages') would then be a series of rows, collecting these various steps into different groups for example:

Prepare Sponge: Step_# 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 {from Table 1}

Bake and Rest: Step_# 8,9 {from Table 1}

Dice fruit and chill: Step_# 193,194,306 (etc - table 1 will be huge and this example was quite limited and boring).

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to achieve this (foreign keys/logic?) in MySQL? Is this even possible?

Cheers

EDIT:
Each step will need to be called in to multiple stages. (Thanks Dan).

Comment: FOR ANSWER: See Daniel's comment to his own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to `steps` table new column named `stage_id` and keep in this column id of stages.

Comment: I think this would limit - which admittedly i hadn't spelled out - using any step in more than one stage. I'll edit to make this point. Thanks for your response.

Comment: In this case, you can apply many to many relation.

Let crate table `steps_stages` with column `step_id` and `stage_id`. Then any connection between `stages` and `steps` is in this table. You can have some stages for one step and some steps for one stage.

This solution do not provide ordering. To add order of `step` in `stage` you can add also column `order` to table `steps_stages`. This relation is called "many to many with parameter".

Comment: I think that'll be it! I hadn't heard of many-to-many so I will look into that. Thanks